# Scope of an argument of a function

Tags: python

I am trying to get the following recursive function to work. It is supposed to find the biggest list of vectors in vspace(n) such that all the vectors are at least distance d from each other. My current issue is that the variable sol does not seem to be behaving locally. For some reason when the code shifts back to earlier iterations, the variable sol does not revert back to what it was in that iteration of bestCode. Any ideas?

rlist is a function that reduced a list of vectors by removing any that are too close to x (less than distance d).

```
def bestCode(n, d, sol):   
    best=[]
    v = vspace(n)
    for i in range(0, len(sol)):
        v = rlist(sol[i], v, d)
    if(len(v) != 0):
        for i in range(0, len(v)):
                sol2 = sol
                sol2.append(v[i])
                sol2 = bestCode(n, d, sol2)
            if(len(sol2)>len(best)):
                best = sol2
        return best
    else:
        return sol
```

Comment: Aside: `for i in range(0, len(v)): v[i]` is a long, error-prone way of writing `for element in v: element`.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation so this code will actually work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: `sol2 = sol` creates a new reference to the list referenced by `sol`. If you want `sol2` to be a new list so that operations on `sol2` don't change the original list, you should copy `sol2 = sol[:]`.

Comment: THATS IT @tdelaney THANKS! If you put in an answer I can accept it

Comment: @SeanBallentine The comment above has been converted into an answer by its author which I encourage you to accept. Glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python variables are references to objects. Assignment such as `sol2 = sol` just creates a new reference to the object. For mutable objects like lists, changes to `sol2` are seen by `sol` because they both reference the same list. If you want `sol2` to be independent, you need to copy. For lists, the normal way to do that is `sol2 = sol[:]`.